# Webscraping with regex problem with loop and variables

Tags: python, regex, loops, variables, web-scraping

Could you please help me debug this piece of code?
I suspect there's an issue with the variables and the '' or "", but I can't figure out what's the problem.

```
import requests
import re

urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
regexes = ['regex1', 'regex2', 'regex3']

url1 = 'https://...' 
regex1 = r'(\d+\.)\s+([^\n][A-Za-z]+)<\/a>'
url2 = 'https://...' 
regex2 = "r'\/review\/([^\n][A-Za-z]+)'"
url3 = 'https://...' 
regex3 = "r'(\d+\.)\s+([^\n][A-Za-z]+)'"


for url, regex in zip(urls, regexes):
    r = requests.get(url)
    results = re.findall(regex, r.text)

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues with the code above are:

- Regexen are specified with enclosing double quotes which they shouldn't
- the `urls` and `regexes` lists should contain the `url_` and `regex_` variables instead of the string literals, resp.
- With the given indentation, `print(results)` outputs the matches of the last iteration only.

Re-coded:

```
import requests
import re


url1 = 'https://...' 
regex1 = r'(\d+\.)\s+([^\n][A-Za-z]+)<\/a>'
#
# ... other urls/regexen
#

urls = [url1, url2, url3]
regexes = [regex1, regex2, regex3]


for (url, regex) in zip(urls, regexes):
    r = requests.get(url)
    results = re.findall(regex, r.text)
    print(results)
```

A demo is available [here (repl.it)](https://repl.it/@CarstenBeck/ScrapeAndFilter) (it uses specific urls and a simpler regex on the first iteration in order to produce actual matches).